# CakePHP Error: Class 'String' not found in Acl

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, deprecated, cakephp-2.x

My Acl admin is corrupt and I have no idea why, since I haven't changed anything from when it used to work.

When I go to `/acl`, I get the following error:

> Error: Class 'String' not found 
>       File: /app/Plugin/Acl/Controller/Component/AclReflectorComponent.php
>       Line: 17

```
public function getPluginName($ctrlName = null)
{
    $arr = String::tokenize($ctrlName, '/');   <-----  Line: 17
    if (count($arr) == 2) {
        return $arr[0];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I checked what's in `$ctrlName` and the value is `Acl/Acl`.

I'm completely lost here, what should I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to make CakePHP compatible with PHP7, the  `String` class has been deprecated as of CakePHP 2.7 in favour of the  `CakeText` class.

You have to download an up to date version of your Acl Plugin.

If you can't find one, changing all occurrences of `String` with `CakeText` should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I was using String in my custom class and getting this error. I replaced String by CakeText and now it's working.